# Passing a null function to java function as argument

Tags: java, function, class, parameters, void

I'm encountering problems understanding how function are passed to methods as parameters.

Searching on StackOverflow and StackExchange has brought me to a solution using `java.util.Functions`

```java
public void someFunction(Functions <int[], int[]> myFunction);
```

(source: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/186972/passing-a-generic-function-as-parameter)

Although this solution seems good to me, I'm facing problem when I need to pass a function which is intended to do nothing. For better understanding, consider the following example:

```java
public class Example {
    //do stuffs
    myFunction(null);
}

public class Manager {
    public void myFunction(Function<int[], void> funcToPass) { // Can't specify void as return value!
        //do stuff
        if(funcToPass != null) { // can't replicate such behaviour
            funcToPass(someParams)
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help me acquiring clear understanding on this topic? Thank you so much.

Comment: a `Function` without return is just a `Consumer`

Comment: I do not consider this a valid answer since I need a more general case. Consumer would limit me to consider only functions with Void return value.

Comment: sure not a valid answer, it is just a comment. but if you define your method that way, there is no way to *change* the function to return anything but what is declared (Void) - anyway that does not matter for question, so I posted it as comment and not answer. And why "can't replicate such behaviour"? should work with Java (assuming correct declaration of function)

Comment: Since it seems not to accept null as a parameter.

Comment: but it does work (again, assuming correct declaration)

Comment: I'm so sorry, you're right. There was some errors on the compiler and I thought it was my fault. Shame on me.

Comment: just for knowledge: `funcToPass` will be a reference to an instance as any parameter that is not of primitive type ([mini-example](http://jdoodle.com/a/1Puo)). In this case implements `Function`, is of type `Function`

Comment: Good to know. This means that I have to call `Test` class method by declaring it as a new instance? Can't I declare the method as `static` and doing something like `Test.apply()`? (Obviously based on the context).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to describe a function that does not return a value, you can use the `Void` type. This is a standard Java class, but is intended for use in this situation.

E.g.

```
Function<String, Void> stringPrinter = s -> {
    System.out.println(s);
    return null;  // must return some value, null is acceptable since there is no Void instance
};
```

The `return null;` is important since, from the compiler's point of view, `Void` is just like any other class (e.g. `String`, `Integer`, etc). It doesn't know that it represents the absence of a value, whereas it does know that a function that returns `void` does not have a return value.

This means the compiler still expects some `return` statement in your code, just as if it were returning an `Integer`, and so you must `return null;`

EDIT:

You may find, however, if you are strictly dealing with functions with no returns, you are better suited to use a `Consumer<T>`. For example:

```
Consumer<String> stringPrinter = s -> System.out.println(s);
stringPrinter.accept("hello");
```

or, using a method reference:

```
Consumer<String> stringPrinter = System.out::println;
stringPrinter.accept("hello");
```

Comment: actually `return null` is the only option, not just acceptable, since there is no possible instance of `Void`

Comment: This means I can use a lambda function which returns null as a result?

Comment: Another question: it is not possible then to pass `null` as function parameter instead of this place-filler function?

Comment: `null` is a valid value for all classes in Java, so you can pass `null` to any parameter that expects a class (i.e. any type except `int`, `long`, etc). However, calling `function.apply(someValue)` will throw a `NullPointerException` if `function` is `null`.

Comment: well so if I just check null value I solved my problem... trying this right now

Answer (score 0):

You can use Reflection API to pass a `void` method as a reference e.g.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class[] classParams = new Class[1];
        classParams[0] = String.class;
        Method method = Main.class.getMethod("hello", classParams);
        Main obj = new Main();
        System.out.println(new Main().getSum(obj, method, "world!", 10, 20));
    }

    public void hello(String msg) {
        System.out.println("Hello " + msg);
    }

    int getSum(Object object, Method method, String msg, int x, int y) throws Exception {
        Object[] objectParams = new Object[1];
        objectParams[0] = msg;
        method.invoke(object, objectParams);
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hello world!
30
```

Comment: While this does work, the type safety and performance costs do not justify using reflection in this case, especially when there are good alternative solutions

Comment: So, if I'm not wrong, this works by passing parameters of `hello` method as `classParams` variable of type `Class`?

Comment: Parameter to `hello` method is `"world!"`. Basically, you are passing `method` as the reference of `hello` method to `getSum` method from where you are invoking  `hello` method using the reference.

Comment: Subtle, but indeed a possible solution.

Comment: Thanks, @KingPowa for the feedback.